# href does not work in dropdown menu on IOS 7.x

Tags: html, ios7

I have a dropdown menu on my site - http://lady-cosmetics.ru/

The problem is that if I click on any  link from dropped menu nothing happens. It behaves just like if I click not on the link, but on empty space, the menu only disappears.
Try to roll over the last item of the menu and you'll see what I mean.
The problem exists only on IOS 7.x in any browser.

Here is html of the menu:

```
<ul>            
    ....
       <li class="has-sub">
           <a href="#">Все бренды</a>                
           <ul class="subMenu">
               <li>
                   <a target="_self" href="/collection/emerald-bay">Emerald Bay</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a target="_self" href="/collection/gehwol">Gehwol</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </li>
     .....
</ul>
```

As you can see it is just a simple list that converts to dropdown menu by jquery plugin. 
Why links from dropped part of the menu don't work in IOS?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine on my iphone/ipad you can still try doing this thing

```
<ul>            
    ....
       <li class="has-sub">
           <a href="#">Все бренды</a>                
           <ul class="subMenu">
               <li>
                   <a href="/collection/emerald-bay" target="_self">Emerald Bay</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="/collection/gehwol" target="_self">Gehwol</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </li>
     .....
</ul>
```